# Memory allocation in 64-bit R on Windows 10

Tags: r, memory, windows-10, 64-bit

I'm calculating pairwise summary stats on some large datasets in R (using RStudio on Windows 10) which is taking a while (~15 hours per replicate).

I have 80Gb of RAM available

```
> memory.limit()
[1] 81871
```

But on the Resource Monitor, rsession.exe never uses more than 1.4Gb. There's no set max memory limit that I can find in System Configuration. Is there a reason to think that R is being kept from accessing more RAM by some nefarious Microsoft settings, or is it more likely the function I'm using is not set up for efficient memory usage?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3
```

Comment: Seems far more likely the function you're using is not set up for efficient memory usage, but without any specific details, it's impossible to say for sure. But I've not seen Windows limiting R RAM usage for most "normal" windows installs.

Comment: Thank for that. I've been suspecting the code, but I don't know enough about Windows to be sure it wasn't throttling RAM.